# Laravel Change Login URL - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

i want change laravel login url from `/auth/login` to `login`

already make change in AuthController

```
protected $loginPath = 'login';
```

and routes

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

i can access login page if manually go to that page

but if redirect to login page after trying to access page already protected with Middleware its still redirect to `/auth/login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the middleware folder app\Http\Middleware. Edit the Authenticate file

```
return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
```

to be

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Route::get('your_custom/login_path', [
    'as'   => 'login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);
```

You don't need to add or modify any other file. Here is why:

As of writing this answer, Laravel is at 5.4 mark. At this point you no longer have $loginPath.
The guys at Laravel also did a nice job in updating the platform as in they replace

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

with

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

which makes really easy overriding routes because their pointed by their names now (and not hard coded).

(this is a bonus tip - for security - limiting the number of attempt logins) Just added it at the end.

```
->middleware('throttle:3,1');
```